# Arduino COM port doesn't work

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I bought an Arduino Uno recently. After getting the necessary cables, I decided to upload an example to the chip.

Instead of seeing that Blink, I received an error like `processing.app.SerialException: Serial port 'COM1' not found.  Did you select the right one from the Tools > Serial Port menu?`

Yes, I tried that. But even Serial Port Monitor doesn't seem opening. Then again, I get some exception that isn't worth mentioning.

After I found out that my Serial COM ports don't work (via Portmon.exe), and figuring out that I may even don't have any (there is no COM port in Device Manager), I also tried to download a driver for COM port, but it has also failed.

Some say that it's because of my Acer Aspire 5742's motherboard. Some say that the reason is Windows 7.

Long story short, I'd really appreciate if someone can help me with my COM port problem and mend my broken dreams.

Comment: It can be a broken cable, too. I had this issue that the official Arduino cable did not work, but my Samsung mobile loading cable worked properly...

Comment: I used usb cable came with my power bank. As in https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=505238.0 I replaced it with cable came with mobile, it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install the drivers? See the Arduino [installation instructions](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Windows) under #4. I don't know that machine but I doubt it doesn't have *any* COM ports.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. :) I took your advice and went to the site, it says /*While in the Control Panel, navigate to System and Security. Next, click on System. Once the System window is up, open the Device Manager.
Look under Ports (COM & LPT).  You should see an open port named "Arduino UNO (COMxx)"*/ right? But i don't see any COM or Ports or anything like that. That's the thing what really troubles me.

Comment: So after following the steps they describe (plugging in board, installing driver, etc.) there is no port listed? That's odd. Does the board LED light up to indicate it is getting power? Do you get the alert about "new hardware found"? I guess if you did all that then you are in some special tech hell.. Maybe post your question on the Arduino forum - bigger audience there. Good luck!

Comment: Ouch! I was terribly wrong! Thank you for your great help! I was expecting to see some ports (anything) before i install the driver. I guess that was the point that i've mistaken. So it works perfectly now. :)

Comment: Note that if you get a second Arduino of a different model, then you will have to do the driver-installation steps again.  For instance I  had been using an "old" Uno, then got a new "Esplora" --they are both listed as Com3 when plugged into the right side USB port of my laptop, but a different number for the other side.  One other point of confusion is that the subMenu under the Serial Port menu needs to be selected, even if it is the only choice.  Also, don't forget to change "Board" menu.

Answer (score 23):

Installing Drivers for Arduino in Windows 8 / 7.

( I tried it for Uno r3, but i believe it will work for all Arduino Boards )

Plugin your Arduino Board

Go to **Control Panel** ---> **System and Security** ---> **System** ---> On the left pane **Device Manger**

Expand **Other Devices**.

Under Other Devices you will notice a icon with a **small yellow error graphic**. (Unplug all your other devices attached to any Serial Port)

Right Click on that device ---> **Update Driver Software**

Select **Browse my computer for Driver Software**

Click on Browse ---> **Browse for the folder of Arduino Environmen**t which you have downloaded from Arduino website. If not downloaded then http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

After Browsing **mark include subfolder**.

Click next ---> Your driver will be installed.

Collapse Other Devices ---> **Expand Port** ( its in device manager only under other devices )

You will see Arduino Written ---> Look for its COM PORT (close device manager)

Go to **Arduino Environment** ---> **Tools** ---> **Serial Port** ---> Select the **COM PORT** as mentioned in PORT in device manager. (If you are using any other Arduino Board instead of UNO then select the same in boards )

Upload your killer programmes and see them work . . .

I hope this **helps**. . .

**Welcome**

Comment: For what it's worth, this didn't work for me on Windows 8.1. I had to reboot with driver signature verification off to get the drivers to install. There's an answer at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=205837.0 and the link to http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-can-i-install-hardware-with-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-8/ helped.

The installer I ran is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\drivers. I ran as administrator for good measure. Irritatingly, when it fails without being in the special startup mode, you don't get a dialog showing the unsigned driver warning.

Comment: What if there is no "other devices" listed in the device manager? I'm having this issue with the Arduino Industrial 101 on 2 different computers!!!

Answer (score 2):

I've had my drivers installed and the Arduino connected through an unpowered usb hub.
Moving it to an USB port of my computer made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract: Steps of How to resolve "Serial port 'COM1' not found" in fedora 17.

Today install the packages for Arduino in Fedora 17.
(yum install arduino) and I have the same problem: I decided to upload an example to the chip. and got the same error "Serial port 'COM1' not found".

In this case when I run Arduino program, some banner appears which warns me that my user is not in 'dialout' and 'lock' group. Do you want add your user in this groups? I click in add button, but for some reason the program fail and not say nothing.

**Step1**: recognize the Arduino device
unplug your Arduino and list /dev files:

```
#ls -l /dev
```

plug your Arduino and go and list /dev files

```
#ls -l /dev
```

Find the new file (device) that was not before plugging, for example:

> ttyACM0 or ttyUSB1

Read this properties:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM0

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Dec 24 19:25 /dev/ttyACM0
```

the first c mean that Arduino is a character device.

user owner: root

group owner: dialout

mayor number: 166

minor number: 0

**Step2**: set your user as group owner.

If you do:

```
groups <yourUser>
```

And you are not in 'dialout' and/or 'lock' group. Add yourself in this groups run as root:

```
usermod -aG lock <yourUser>
usermod -aG dialout <yourUser>
```

restart the pc, and set `/dev/<yourDeviceFile>` as your serial port before upload.

Answer (score 0):

unplug not necessary,just uninstall your port,restart and install driver again.you will see arduino COM port under the LPT & PORT section.

Answer (score 0):

This fix / solution worked for me:
Device Manager --> Ports --> right click on Arduino Uno --> Update Driver Software --> Search automatically for updated driver software

Answer (score 0):

uninstall version 2.1.0 of Arduino, after this installs Version 1.8.9 when it is already installed lowers the communication speed of the serial monitor to 1200 baud

Answer (score -1):

I restarted my computer and then opened the IDE again and it worked while none of the above did.

Maybe you have to do the things above as well, but make sure to restart the computer too.

Comment: I think this would be best suited as a comment to the existing answer